# Bibliography in German

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, babel, german

I want to change the bibliography to german. I tried to do this by adding the package `\usepackage{bibgerm}` and changed the `\bibliographystyle{gerplain}`.
But when I change these two things I get the Error:

**"! Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language German yet"**

Without these changes everything in the document works just fine.
Can someone help me?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,      % DinA4
headsepline,                 % Strich unter Kopfzeile
footsepline]{scrreprt}       % Strich über Fußzeile
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % für Umlaute
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  % für Silbentrennung
\usepackage{bibgerm}

\begin{document}
Test, Test \cite{Fertigungstechnik}

\bibliographystyle{gerplain}
\bibliography{literaturverzeichnis}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! Have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Comment: For those who are directed here by a search engine: The package bibgerm is now superseeded by [babelbib](https://ctan.org/pkg/babelbib)

Answer (score 5):

You very likely switched from the `german` to the `ngerman` option with `babel`. In that case, deleting all auxiliary files before compiling helps.